# Why tokenize/preprocess words for language analysis?

Tags: python, nltk, tweepy, analysis

I am currently working on a Python tweet analyser and part of this will be to count common words. I have seen a number of tutorials on how to do this, and most tokenize the strings of text before further analysis.

Surely it would be easier to avoid this stage of preprocessing and count the words directly from the string - so why do this?

Comment: How would you "count words" without tokenizing?

Comment: I suppose using `for i in` is technically tokenizing, but it's not taking the words into a seperate, declared list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps I'm being overly correct, but doesn't tokenization simply refer to splitting up the input stream (of characters, in this case) based on delimiters to receive whatever is regarded as a "token"?

Your tokens can be arbitrary: you can perform analysis on the word level where your tokens are words and the delimiter is any space or punctuation character. It's just as likely that you analyse n-grams, where your tokens correspond to a group of words and delimiting is done e.g. by sliding a window.

So in short, in order to analyse words in a stream of text, you need to tokenize to receive "raw" words to operate on.

Tokenization however is often followed by stemming and lemmatization to reduce noise. This becomes quite clear when thinking about sentiment analysis: if you see the **tokens** `happy`, `happily` and `happiness`, do you want to treat them each separately, or wouldn't you rather combine them to three instances of `happy` to better convey a stronger notion of "being happy"?

Answer (score 1):

This approach is needed in order to be able to tell which word accounts for which dimension in the vector that numerically represents the string. Also it sometimes uses additional editing, like lowercasing words and removing punctuation marks. Let's take a look at the following example:

```
from collections import Counter
import re
sentence = 'This is just some sentence, which is nice.'
tokens = sentence.split(' ')
tokens = [re.sub(r'[,.]', '', t).lower() for t in tokens]
print(Counter(tokens))

# Output:
#   Counter({'is': 2, 'just': 1, 'nice': 1, 'sentence': 1, 'some': 1, 'this': 1, 'which': 1})
```

The sentence first is split into a list and the symbols `,` as well as `.` are removed and it is made sure that the strings are lowercase. Next up is counting the words via `Counter`. You can interpret this result as a vector `[2 1 1 1 1 1 1]` (with `2` representing `is`, `1` the word `just` and so on). If your dictionary is getting bigger, because you are utilizing a much bigger corpus, the vectors get increasingly [sparse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix), which means that they contain more and more zeros, and the information contained within can be stored in a more compressed way.

If you therefore have a sentence that you want to represent numerically it is needed to first create a dictionary of your corpus, like done above with a single sentence, so you can tell which word represents which dimension.

You can try to represent the data above in a [semi-structured](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-structured_data) data format, like JSON, but will see that this is in itself not a well compressed representation of your data. This approach could be combined with (un-)compressing the data before loading or after saving, but this would incur a performance penalty multiple times, while building a dictionary would have only one-time costs.

Comment: Introducing stop word removal would result in less noise for the results, too

Answer (score 1):

Trying with this sentence :

```
text = "We like the cake you did this week, we didn't like the cakes you cooked last week"
```

Count directly without nltk tokens :

```
Counter(text.split())
```

Returns :

```
Counter({'We': 1,
     'cake': 1,
     'cakes': 1,
     'cooked': 1,
     'did': 1,
     "didn't": 1,
     'last': 1,
     'like': 2,
     'the': 2,
     'this': 1,
     'we': 1,
     'week': 1,
     'week,': 1,
     'you': 2})
```

We see that we are not happy with the result. did and didn't (which is the contraction of did not) are counted as different words, so were 'week' and 'week,'

This is fixed when you tokenize using nltk (splitting is in fact one naive way to tokenize):

```
Counter(nltk.word_tokenize(text))
```

Returns

```
Counter({',': 1,
     'We': 1,
     'cake': 1,
     'cakes': 1,
     'cooked': 1,
     'did': 2,
     'last': 1,
     'like': 2,
     "n't": 1,
     'the': 2,
     'this': 1,
     'we': 1,
     'week': 2,
     'you': 2})
```

If you want to count as a same word 'cake' and 'cakes', you can also lemmatize :

```
Counter([lemmatizer.lemmatize(w).lower() for w in nltk.word_tokenize(text)])
```

Returns

```
Counter({',': 1,
     'cake': 2,
     'cooked': 1,
     'did': 2,
     'last': 1,
     'like': 2,
     "n't": 1,
     'the': 2,
     'this': 1,
     'we': 2,
     'week': 2,
     'you': 2})
```

Comment: You might also want to normalize the sentence-initial `"We"` to `"we"`.

Answer (score 0):

Tokenization is an easy way of understanding the lexicon/vocabulary in text processing.

A basic first step in analyzing language or patterns in text is to remove symbols/punctuations and stop words. With tokenization you are able to split the large chunks of text to identify and remove text which might not add value, in many cases, stop words like 'the','a','and', etc do not add much value in identifying words of interest.

Word frequencies are also very common in understanding the usage of words in text, Google's Ngram allows for language analysis and plots out the popularity/frequency of a word over the years. If you do not tokenize or split the strings, you will not have a basis to count the words that appear in a text.

Tokenization also allows you to run a more advanced analysis, for example tagging the part of speech or assigning sentiments to certain words. Also for machine learning, texts are mostly preprocessed to convert them to arrays which are used in te different layers of neural networks. Without tokenizing, the inputs will all be too distinct to run any analysis on.